# Extract each seperate number from string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have this as an input "1 2 3 4 5" and I want to have it like this

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
number[0] = 1;
number[1] = 2;
number[2] = 3;
number[3] = 4;
number[4] = 5;
```

**So how can I extract each number from a string and put it in an int array?**

```
    ConsoleIO io = new ConsoleIO();
    int[] numbers = new int[5];

    io.writeOutput("Type in 5 numbers");

    String input = io.readInput();

    // If input is longer than 1 character for example, "1 2 3 4 5"
    if(input.length() > 1) {
        System.out.println(input.length());
        for(int y = 0; y < io.readInput().length(); y++) {
            numbers[y] = Integer.parseInt(io.readInput().substring(y, io.readInput().indexOf(" "))); 
        }
        return;
    }
    // If input is one number for example, "1"
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(io.readInput());
        }
    }
```

The else works, so if I enter one number and press enter and then the next one, it's all good. But if I have a sequence of numbers with a space in between ("1 2 3 4 5") the program just breaks.

Comment: you can use splite and remove space of java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
String input = io.readInput();
int[] arr = new int[5];

if(input.length() >= 5){
    String[] c = input.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++){
        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(c[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails in two situations: the code doesn't give an error if there are less than five inputs; and the code dies when there are more than five inputs, since you go off the end of `arr`, which is 5 long. You should either not have the `if` condition at all and initialize `arr` after `c` is determined so that you can set its length to the length of `c` or you should give an error if there aren't exactly five values.

Comment: I only wanted to show him the split method and how to use it, not to show him all the required code for his program. He actually just texted me that this answer helped in his program. He already created the whole 'anti-fool' system which checks for wrong input, so it had no use for him to type out the whole source code

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `Scanner` and then [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and `parse`?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] nums = in.nextLine().split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i <=5; i++) {
   numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
}
```

Comment: you can add Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); in for loop

Comment: @AbdessamadHALLAL That would create a new `Scanner` object ever iteration of the loop, and would also require the `String[] nums = in.nextLine().split(" ");` to be inside the loop, which would cause problems

Comment: I believe this also worked, but I choose @Joeri Akkerman's answer because he used the io I already used. Thanks for your answer tho.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your input is always numbers with a space between each other (or just one number), in Java 8 you can work in this way:

```
String[] splits = input.split(" ");
int[] result =  Arrays.stream(splits).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] nums = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        int[] numbers = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```