# Use Java Stream to parse a string of digits as a List of Integer objects

Tags: java, parsing, java-stream, boxing

My Question is inspired by [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52506765/642706), but is aimed at using Java Streams to arrive an a `List<Integer>`.

I have this code that kind of works. It seems to be returning an `ArrayList`, presumably `ArrayList<Integer>`. But the compiler refuses to let me declare the result as such.

```
String input = "1 2 3 4 5";
Stream stream = Arrays.stream( input.split( " " ) );
var x = stream.map( s -> Integer.valueOf( ( String ) s ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

This runs when using the new `var` feature of recent Java versions.

```
System.out.println( x.getClass() );
System.out.println( x );
```

> class java.util.ArrayList
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

I have two questions:

- Why is `x` reported as an `ArrayList` yet I cannot declare `x` to be an ArrayList (error: incompatible types), such as:
  `ArrayList<Integer> x = stream.map( s -> Integer.valueOf( ( String ) s ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );`
- Is there a better way to use streams to convert this string of digits to a `List` of `Integer`?

Comment: You need to declare your stream `Stream<String> stream`.

Comment: When it is truly about processing *digits*, you can use `var x = input.chars().filter(c -> c != 32).map(c -> c-'0').boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your `Stream` is raw.  Using a raw type means that anything that uses a type parameter is erased to its upper bound, here `Object`.  So `map` returns another raw `Stream` and `collect` returns an `Object`.  Easy fix: `Stream<String>`.

```
Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream( input.split( " " ) );
```

Second, [`Collectors.toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) is specified to return `List<T>`, or `List<String>` here.

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the `List` returned; if more control over the returned `List` is required, use `toCollection(Supplier)`.

If you aren't satisfied with `List` and you absolutely need an `ArrayList`, supply one:

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Incidentally, you can replace the lambda expression

```
s -> Integer.valueOf( ( String ) s )
```

with the method reference

```
Integer::valueOf
```

After these changes, your code might look like this:

```
String input = "1 2 3 4 5";
Stream< String > stream = Arrays.stream( input.split( " " ) );
List< Integer > x = stream.map( Integer::valueOf ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Or, if you insist on precisely `ArrayList` rather than `List`, make that:

```
String input = "1 2 3 4 5";
Stream< String > stream = Arrays.stream( input.split( " " ) );
ArrayList< Integer > x = stream.map( Integer::valueOf ).collect( Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList::new ) );
```

Once these changes are made, this seems like a reasonably good way of converting a string containing space-separated integers to an `ArrayList<Integer>`.  A minor improvement would be to change the `split` regular expression argument to `"\\s+"`, to represent one or more whitespace characters.  In case `"1  2"` arrives, with multiple spaces between numbers, this will prevent empty strings that would match in between space characters.

Comment: Don't build intermediate array. Replace `Arrays.stream( input.split( " " ) )` with `Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(input)`

Comment: @Andreas I do appreciate seeing your suggestion demonstrated in the [Answer by Oleksandr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526967/642706). But I value this Answer as-is because it maintains the context of my original code while clarifying and correcting my misunderstandings.

Comment: @BasilBourque Guess I should have put that comment in the question, huh. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `ArrayList`, but you shouldn't:

```
ArrayList<Integer> x =
    stream.map(Integer::valueOf)
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Refactoring:

```
List<Integer> x =
    Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
          .map(Integer::valueOf)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, with the [`Pattern.splitAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
List<Integer> x =
    Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream("1 2 3 4 5")
           .map(Integer::valueOf)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream("1 2 3 4 5".split(" ")).map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This compiles. According to the [collectors source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java): "There are no guarantees on the type, mutability,
     * serializability, or thread-safety of the {@code List} returned;"

Answer (score 1):

> Why is x reported as an ArrayList yet I cannot declare x to be an ArrayList.

Because

1. `collect(...)` is returning a statically inferred type, based on the type of the result of `Collectors.toList()`.
2. That is (in this case) `Collector<String,​?,​List<String>>` ... according to the `Collectors` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()).

The fact that the actual object is an `ArrayList` is an implementation detail that could conceivably change in future versions of Java.

> Is there a better way to use streams to convert this string of digits to a List of Integer?

I will leave that to others to say.  However, I think that a simpler / cleaner way to do this is to not use streams for this task.

```
    String input = "1 2 3 4 5";
    var x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")));
```

The above code is simpler and most likely more efficient than the streams-based versions I have seen.